# Response.TransmitFile OnSucess OnFail? Also, how many concurrent downloads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I've got an app that user's can download a file through. I need to log when the file transfer completed successfully and also when it failed. Is this possible with Response.TransmitFile. Here is my code:

```
      Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileSaveName + "\"");
      Response.TransmitFile(zipPath);
      Response.End();
```

ALSO, the files I am serving will be about 20-50MB and could take a bit of time to download. It is very possible that the # of concurrent downloads could be about a 100. Is this possible? Is something else recommended for this etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you split the file transfer operation into a separate thread, you can log the time at which the thread starts and the time when it ends. Threading your file transfer operations should also let you handle file transfers asynchronously. Check out System.Threading.